# How to pass image urls to a feed_dict in tensorflow session?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to pass image urls through feed_dict for inference from a tensorflow app deployed in Google Cloud Platform for a locally trained model as all my images are stored in Google cloud storage.

I tried this:

```
   logits = sess.run([pred], feed_dict = {image_paths_placeholder:urllib.urlopen(img_file).read()})
```

But I am getting this error:

```
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0:invalid start byte.
```

Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong here? or some other way around.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/inception.py#L353)  is and example on how to use "feed_dict":

```
   image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

    # Image is passed in as a jpeg-encoded image.
    feed_dict = {self.tensor_name_input_jpeg: image_data}
```

In your case you can:

```
    image_data = urllib.urlopen(img_file).read()
    logits = sess.run([pred], feed_dict = {image_paths_placeholder:image_data})
```